# Откуда лишний пробел в подсказке рейтинга по метке в профиле участника?

Tags: поддержка, локализация

В профиле участника есть рейтинг по меткам:

> [image: рейтинг по метке]

Видно, что между предложениями используется 2 пробела. Для уверенности можно посмотреть в [html-код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/alexolut?tab=profile):

> ```
> ... рейтингом, равным 59.  Опубликовал 245 ...
> ```

[Первое предложение на transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267845?key=16b3a69a43c5f58ae911dc82cde0639a) содержит в конце один пробел.
[Второе предложение](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267101?key=68c409302edf05abdef22334f29387bd) не содержит пробела в начале.
Очевидная гипотеза, что при склеивании двух предложений добавляется ещё один пробел и получаем два. Но на enSO например удвоения пробелов нет:

> [image: enSO top tags]

Откуда же берётся второй пробел на ruSO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ лежал на поверхности. Пробел содержался **только лишь** в русском переводе. Убрал его [во всех упомянутых строках](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?key=8bcd435ce7d4ca10b96488fd8413972c).

Скоро будет на сайте.